# Error al publicar un WebService .NET en IIS : Atributo "targeFramework" no reconocido

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webservice, iis

Buenos días,

He desarrollado un Webservice en Visual Studio 2017, y localmente en mi máquina funciona perfectamente, lo puedo ejecutar y compruebo que devuelve los resultados esperados.

Pero cuando intento publicarlo en el Servidor IIS de producción (he subido todo el proyecto a una carpeta bajo inetpub/wwwroot y he definido una nueva Aplicación en el gestor de IIS apuntando a ese carpeta), me encuentro con este error :

> **Mensaje de Error del analizador :** Atributo "targetFramework" no reconocido. Tenga en cuenta que en los nombres de atributo se
>   distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor, ¿ que más me he olvidado de configurar para ejecutar ese servicio ?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Con que Pool configuraste tu App en el IIS?

Comment: Gracias por contestar. En el pool ya existente, DefaulAppPool, o algo similar.

Comment: Gracias por encontrar esa solución @Pikoh, voy a probar si también resuelve mi caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, esa solución corrige mi problema.